# Do I need a web-service for this case? Data-synchronization over multiple clients

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, synchronization

I'm new in this area and a little bit confused about my current thoughts on a web-service implementation for my application. I want to synchronize all connected clients with the current data on a MySQL DB. I came up to use web-services as for coordination purposes, but I got stuck.

The way I tried to implement it is...

The web-service is running a deamon to check/listen on CRUD operations affecting DB data. Once an CRUD operation has been occured it undetakes to notify all the connected clients and each client in turn refreshes the JTable with current DB data and informs the user with the change that took place on the DB.

This is where I'm stuck...

The way I'm thinking it's (maybe?) wrong, since conceptually web-services are awaiting for client requests and then send him the corresponding response. But here, there is no client requests. The web-service just sends a response (noification), which must multicast since it's unaware of a "calling" client -there's no request.

Therefore, in order a client to send a request it must "cron" all the time the web-service if a change on the DB has been occured. Then the web-service responts as true or false with the CRUD details (CRUDEventFired(event_type, event_details)). But, this is not optimal as it will create big and (much of time) useless traffic especially when there is no CRUD operation occured. Also, there will be two different deamons (one in web-service and the other in client-app) that check/listen for the same type of event and that's redundant.

Also, with that implementation it seems that there's no need for a web-service at all and the code to check the DB for changes could be implemented in the client. On the other hand setting the client responsible for the DB changes would require to code the same functions in different platforms (desktop, ios, android, etc), while setting the web-service as the coordinator for data synchronization between clients would require to code only once the appropriate function and each client simply implement its own NotificationListener().

Is it wrong the way I'm thinking using web-services? How it should be changed? Do I even need to use web-services?

I attach my diagram for your convinience.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Why not just send a notification to the client when a change occurs and then let them log onto the web service requesting the changes. Each client stores the last synch date time and send that up when they get a notification from the server. You can push notifications via https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Without knowing much of android web services I will read the recommended docs and come back.

Though, I would like to ask 2 questions.

Comment: 1. How is it possible for the web-service to know the list of the connected (online) clients, as to push the notifications? I suppose because they will be all (web-service/clients) under the Google Cloud..?

2.  What about my desktop (Windows OS) clients?

Comment: @Namphibian
Also, since clients connect to the MySQL database with JDBC driver then they can refresh their GUI (a JTable with the database data) executing a query with SELECT * FROM my_table. So, this way they get "synchronized". The only thing that is required is a signal/notification that has to be fired/sent as to perform the refresh/update.

According to what you propose that would fit the case where there are thousands/millions of records, as to SELECT only the new/edited record. However, I assume that this would make some complex coding/algorithm in client app as to rearrange the results

Comment: So, I conclude to ask where this signal/notification is most preferable to be implemented? In web-service with somehow push technique or in the client app without using web-services at all?

I'm really sory for the multiple posts.

Comment: Nope it is as simplr as a trigger on a column called updated_on. This column is updated to a new date time on every update. The clients maintain their last datetime of checking in. When they recieve a notification they simply query data with an updated_on value that is bigger than their last datetime value. No need to cmplicate it.

Comment: Web-services either SOAP/REST cannot push data. If you need both windows and android updated then you will need to either do it on a cron basis or create a custom tcp ip server which can send out the push notification. It is very hard to say what is going to be efficient without seeing the data and how it is supposed to he used.

Comment: @Namphibian
I think I got the point now. I should either make use of GWT or similar push-data-toolkit or as you mentioned to create my custom tcp-ip server using sockets. Either way no need or no appliance of web-services.  Am I right?

Comment: @Namphibian  After some reading I'm currently thinking about two options.  
1. Use a Push-API that supports Windows Desktops too (like UrbanAirship [link](http://urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources) -but I think it's only for Windows 8 and MQTT [link](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/software?id=software) -which is over TCP/IP and kinda frustrating for me.  
2. Just write my tcpip server.  
Which one should I use best?  
So, no need for web-services right?  
Sorry for douple post but I would like to clarify my previous one.